# Dimension of Conjugacy class in $SU(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider $D \in SU(n)$ ($n$ a multiple of 4), a diagonal matrix with values $\pm 1$ on the diagonal and with trace 0 (only possible for $n$ a multiple of 4). There are $n \choose n/2$ such matrices.

What is the dimension of the conjugacy class $\left\{Ad_{V}(D) \ | \ V \in SU(n) \right\}$. of such a $D$?

Comment: Isn't the condition on $n$ a bit stronger?  It seems you need $n \equiv 0$ mod $4$ to satisfy both the determinant and trace condition.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've edited.

Comment: Can you compute the dimension of the centralizer?

Comment: The centralizer of what? Each $D$ is presume?

Comment: Of course. ${}{}$

Comment: if so then yes, it can be found here: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225435/161684

Comment: Well, that's without the trace condition. But this will only reduce it by 1 i think.

Comment: Well the orbit, as a manifold, is the quotient of the group by the centralizer, so you can figure out the dimension easily then!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23976/discussion-between-benjamin-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).

Comment: Will this dimension be $dim(SU(n)) - dim(\text{centeralizer(D)})$?